# How to make a slider continue the loop even if its elements ends (how to wrap a slider)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a slider with `css` and html and `jQuery`.The slider is working great with next button but not whit previous button.

Let us say I have five element on the first slide and total 15 elements . 
so If I click next for three times the elements will end. On the forth click it should show the first five elements (and that is working good) BUT If I click previous button for the first time it should show me the last five elements from 11-15 but it does not do this. It is still showing me the next five element from 6-10.

This link will explain what I want to say :

http://jsfiddle.net/mpx83tpv/10/

Answer (score 0):

It's because the logic in the `previous` button is the same as the `next` button, how do you expect it to work differently?

I changed your previous function to this and it works now,

```
$(".prev_button").click(function(){
    $("ul.slider").animate({
        left: "+=855"
    }, 3000, function(){
        $("ul.slider").css('left', '0');
        $('ul.slider li:gt(12)').prependTo('ul.slider'); // << line changed
    });
});
```

You can test it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mpx83tpv/11/

Comment: Thank u but it still not wrapped.
I mean when u click next the forth time you will see the first five elements start to show before the animation ends .
but in the previous button when u click u do not see the new elements until the whole animation ends .

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can be use full can check and review it

```
 **http://jsfiddle.net/0x8c7ocy**
```